# Core Data rollback is undoing changes from a previous non-transaction operation in another thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, transactions, rollback

This is a complicated one.
We have a IOS app that sometime runs a long running task in the background, updating the database.  Use do create a separately managed Object context and share the persistent store coordinator.

We also add Notification listeners and pass change notifications to the relevant contexts processPendingChanges method. (handled in both directions)

What we are seeing is that the background thread is deleting several objects - NOT in a transaction.  The background thread completes and saves all changes.  Then an operation is done in the foreground where it does a rollback.

This is causing some of the deleted objects to re-appear.  (executeFetchRequest finds them.)  These objects are NOT valid, and making use of them will crash the app.

This only happens if the foreground context has accessed those objects at some time before the background thread deletes them. (i.e. they are in the cache.)  I have checked to make sure that the change notifications from the background are being sent to the foreground context, and are being handled on the foreground thread.

I've verified that the objects don't exist in the foreground context before the call to rollback, and that they do exist after the rollback.  (but aren't completely valid.)  It really seems like the foreground context isn't dropping the deleted objects from it's cache when it receives the change notification from the background context.

Comment: Could you share a code sample depicting this issue? What are the merge policies set for the contexts? how do you merge changes (didsave or didchange)? are you processing pending changes in the merge? do you save the merged context if it has changes?

Comment: There is a LOT of code involved, scattered over a large area.  I'll see if I can extract the relevant parts...